# Hosting a Shiny app without Shiny Server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I am running a Shiny app through Rscript.exe on a server that hosts to my local network. If we were to port this online, we could do so through the server infrastructure we have set up.

Does Shiny Server add anything or is it just another type of hosting infrastructure?

Comment: With Shiny Server you get management functionalities and multiple apps support. See http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/ for complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing via RStudio. Without knowing more about your business case, I don't think you would need Shiny Server.